# No columns to parse from file (EmptyDataError: )

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text

I have a text file like the following one:

```
289222
image_name  category_label
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000001.jpg                        3
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000002.jpg                        3
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000003.jpg                        3
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000004.jpg                        3
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000005.jpg                        3
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000006.jpg                        3
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000007.jpg                        3
```

using the following line of code, I can read the data without any problems!

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,skiprows=1, sep='\s+')
```

But when using the above code for the following text file, it gives this error

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

```
289222
image_name  x_1  y_1  x_2  y_2
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000001.jpg                        072 079 232 273
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000002.jpg                        067 059 155 161
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000003.jpg                        065 065 156 200
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000004.jpg                        051 062 167 182
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000005.jpg                        046 088 166 262
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000006.jpg                        047 067 211 241
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and as it might be useful for others. Here is the solution:

Using Notepad or any other text editor, we can simply replace the long tab spaces with just one tab space. Then, the file would be something like this;

```
289222
image_name  x_1  y_1  x_2  y_2
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000001.jpg 072 079 232 273
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000002.jpg 067 059 155 161
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000003.jpg 065 065 156 200
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000004.jpg 051 062 167 182
img/Sheer_Pleated-Front_Blouse/img_00000005.jpg 046 088 166 262
```

And we can use the following line of code to read it.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename,
                      skiprows=1,
                     delim_whitespace=True)
```

Hope this is useful for others. 
Any other solution would be appreciated!